# New CSS class on landing page exposes tag regex issue

Tags: bug, status-completed, homepage, ignored-tags

I am not sure if it is just affecting stackoverflow.com or others too.

When you have an ignored tag with a wildcard prefix, tags can be matched incorrectly.

I have been using `*js` for a long time as an ignored tag, but from this week, the stackoverflow.com landing page just hides all the questions regardless. If you go to `/questions` everything is working as it should.

This seems to be caused by a new CCS class added to the landing page questions, `js-tags`.

**Repro and verification:**

1. Add `*js` as an ignored tag
2. Reload page, all questions gone
3. Run the following JS from dev tools to 'reverse' the bug

```
$(".js-tags").removeClass('js-tags');
StackExchange.tagPreferences.applyPrefs(true, [], undefined);
```

4. All questions are shown correctly again

**Issue:**

It would seem on the landing page, tags are not collected correctly. It should only be reading `t-.+`, but it seems to read anything with a `-`. This can be verified by adding an ignored tag as `*s-tags` which with still match the `js-tags` class which is on every question.

Comment: Repro'ed. Actually, no need to even reload the page.

Comment: Looks like it has been fixed :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed. This was caused by an overzealous regex replacing `*` with `.+`, causing elements with a class attribute like `t-tagname js-whatever` to be matched. The fix was to change the regex to not match spaces (`[^\s]+`), which restricts the matches to single classes only. I'm honestly surprised this hadn't come up sooner, as something like `*-*` (no tags with `-`s in them, which is probably an unrealistic filter) would cause basically every element to be selected.

Comment: Is it possible that the fix somehow triggered [this bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415642/8967612)?

Comment: A spare `console.log` in the production code was added around to the JS around there very recently. In full.en.js, look for the line: ``if (console.log(`ignored: ${c}, interested: ${l}`),``

Comment: For interest sake, how long was this bug present? It is always 'fun' to have an innocent change expose something a lot worse :D

Comment: @CertainPerformance Oops, thanks for the report, I'll get it cleaned up asap.

Comment: @leppie Judging from the git history, looks like ~4 years now! I think nobody noticed because the likelihood of a user crafting a wildcard search that was both useful _and_ matched incorrect class names was very unlikely.

Comment: @BenKelly OT: I once had to ask Marc to delete my ignored tags on the DB because I had so many that it literally got out of hand, think 1000's. Was impossible to cleanup. Each deletion would take like at least half a minute. That list was over a lot of years, but after I went to the few with wildcards as the suggestion engine was a lot better then.